# Uniform convergence of $\tan(x)^n$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I am considering the uniform convergence of $(\tan(x))^n$ in the interval$[0,π/4)$. This function sequence is pointwise convergent everywhere in the given interval and converges to $0$.
 Is this function uniform convergent in the given interval? In my opinion, it is uniform convergent because the supremum of $|f_n(x)-f(x)|$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$ is $0$. Then by the $M_n$ test, we can say that the given function sequence is uniformly convergent. 
Had the interval been $[0,π/4]$, the function sequence would have pointwise converged to a discontinuous function and hence been not uniform convergent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not uniformly convergent. Let $x_n=\arctan (1-\frac 1 n)$. Then  $0<x_n <\frac {\pi} 4$ and $(\tan x_n)^{n}=(1-\frac 1 n )^{n} \to\frac  1 e$ so $\sup_x (tanx )^{n}$ does not tend to $0$.

Comment: Does this mean that $x^n$ is not uniformly convergent in the interval $[0,1)$?

Comment: Yes, it is not uniformly convergent. @HARVEERRAWAT